# Magento 2.4 Order Place Error

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-community, magento2.4.5p1

[image][image]

Errors:
**Something went wrong with your request. Please try again later.**
**No such entity with cartId = 5**

Comment: Remove all product from current cart, try to compile one's and then check.

Comment: There are too less information to answer this question. You need to tell us more about your environment. Check the error logs of your webserver and magento itself. Do you use a third party payment provider? Do you use a third party delivery service? Please invest more time to create good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way.

1. Remove all the items from current cart.
2. Run upgrade and deploy commands.
3. Run compilation command.
4. Try again with add to cart.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error after cancelling the payment then you need to install this patch -

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/6103262032141-MDVA-43824-Order-cancellation-action-failed-with-error-You-have-not-cancelled-the-item-

1. Install Quality Patch -

   composer require magento/quality-patches
2. Run this command -

   ./vendor/bin/magento-patches apply MDVA-43824

Hope it solved your problem.

If this is not the case then check if any module is clearing your cart by disabling each module of third party.